# Vectors, Lines and Planes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I have a question in high school math, vectors to be precise:

> The point $K(3.5,-0.5,-2)$ is the intersection point of the plane $S_1: mx-7my+5z+3=0$ with the line $l_1: (n,1,-2)+t(-1,1,0)$
>
> a) find the parameters $n$ and $m$
>
> b) find the equation of the plane that contains the line $l_1$ and is orthogonal to the plane $S_1$.
>
> c) Another line is given, $l_2: (2,0,-1)+t(3,-3,0)$. Find the area of the parallelogram which has two vertices on $l_2$ and to other vertices are $K$, and another point $E(1,2,-2)$ which is on $l_1$.

I managed to solve (a) and found that $m=1$, $n=2$.

In order to find the parameters, I did:

$$m(n-t)-7m(1+t)+5*(-2)+3=0$$

Then I put $K$ on the equation of the plane, and found the parameters.

I need your assistance with the other part of the question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For (b) notice that $(1,-7,5)$ is orthogonal to $S_1$ and hence must be parallel to $S_2$.  Also $(-1,1,0)$ must be parallel to $S_2$.  So the cross product of those two vectors will be orthogonal to $S_2$.  Using that and the fact that $(2,1,-2)\in S_2$, you can find the equation for $S_2$.

Comment: For (c) choose two points on $l_2$ that make the four points the vertices of a parallelogram (there are infinitely many such pairs, but the parallelogram you get will have always have the same area).  Then use the shoelace formula to calculate its area.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{n}(a,b,c)$ is a normal of the plain, which the equation we need to find.

Hence, $a-7b+5c=0$ and $-a+b=0$, which gives $b=a$ and $c=\frac{6}{5}a$.

Let $a=5$, which gives $\vec{n}(5,5,6)$ and we get an equation of the plain:
$$5(x-2)+5(y-1)+6(z+2)=0$$ or
$$5x+5y+6z-3=0.$$

In c) since $l_1||l_2$, we need to find the distance $d$ between $E$ and $l_2$, which is for you.